# Existence of a splitting

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

This would be well-known, but I don't know of a reference or a quick proof.

Up to one suspension, the space $P_n^{n+2}$ with $n\equiv0\mathrm{mod}4$ splits as $S^n\vee (S^{n+1}\cup_{2}e^{n+2})$, that is 
$$\Sigma P_n^{n+2}\equiv \Sigma(S^n\vee (S^{n+1}\cup_{2}e^{n+2})).$$
But, I think, the space $P_n^{n+2}$ itself does not admit any splitting. How do I see this?!

**EDIT** I think my initial guess above was not correct. To see this notice that by James periodicity, $P_n^{n+2}$ can be obtained from $P_4^6$ by enough suspensions. We can see that spaces we have 
$$P_4^6\simeq S^4\vee (S^5\cup_2 e^6).$$
To see this notice that for $P_4^5$ the attaching map of the $5$-cell is the composition of the projection map $S^4\to P^4$ and the pinch map $P_4\to P^4/P^3=S^4$. It is known that this composition is of degree $0$, hence null. Hence, $P_4^5\simeq S^4\vee S^5$. For the attaching map of the $6$-cell of $P_4^6$, say $S^5\to P_4^5$ one could process similarly, noting that the component $S^5\to S^4$ belongs to $\pi_1^s\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2\{\eta\}$. If it is nontrivial, then there must be a nontrivial action of $Sq^2$ in $P_4^6$ which there is none. Hence, this component is trivial. The other is of degree $2$. This completes the claim.

Still, I would be very interested in to see if there is an invariant to see this rather than using the direct construction.

Comment: You might check out https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102709375#ui-tabs-1 which is about desuspensions of Thom spaces.

Comment: Could you define "splitting"  in this context?

Comment: @HJRW as a wedge!